# Unrecognized selector with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: xcode, swift4, selector, uitapgesturerecognizer, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to add in my app the possibility to dismiss the keyboard when the user taps somewhere else out of the text fields. I'm implementing this functionality using UITapGestureRecognizer. I create a new UITapGestureRecognizer object using the
Unrecognized selector with `UITapGestureRecognizer(target: Any?, action: Selector?)`
and set the action parameter to a function that resigns the first responder of both the text fields I'm using in this view. I set everything properly adding the keyword `@objc` before the method I pass as action and using the `#selector(dismissKeyboard)` form, but when I run the app and tap on the view triggering the function the app crash and the console prints the error

> " Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView dismissKeyboard:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff93790f6b0'
>   *** First throw call stack:"

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set rounded corners
    textFieldView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    logInButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6

    //HERE'S THE ISSUE

    let viewTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTapRecognizer)

    auth = Auth.auth()

}

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    emailTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

I Attach here the screenshots

**First Screenshot**

[image]

**Second Screenshot**

[image]

**Third Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Please show enough code to examine where you are doing wrong. The error message is saying that the `target` of the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is a `UIView` and it has no method `dismissKeyboard:`.

Comment: Copy/paste code and errors, not screenshot. Error is explicit, plenty of question about that. Where did you create the tapGesture?

Comment: @OOPer I’m gonna do this way

Comment: `UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view,` => `UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,` because it's `self` that is implementing and doing the method `func dismissKeyboard()`.

Comment: @OOPer the problem is that i created the method dismissKeyboard inside the ViewController

Comment: _the ViewController_ is `self`, not `self.view`.

Comment: @Larme thank u very much it worked! I didn’t realized that was that easy

Comment: If you look at the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance", there are plenty of question plenty of answers. It's a basic error that every Cocoa(Touch) developer should know (why, how to fix, etc.). So if you give the correct info, we can help you quickly.

Comment: @Larme yeah i Understood the problem was with the selector and the method but i didn’t realize it was because of the wrong target

Comment: That's reading the error. You need to read `-[UIView dismissKeyboard:]`. So there is a method `dismissKeyboard` called on a `UIView` object. `UIView`? Really? It shouldn't.

Comment: @Larme yeah i know...but i’m still a noob i got much to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target of Gesture is (self) not self.view because you are calling all the viewcontroller not just the view inside him,

```
let viewTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTapRecognizer)
```

and if you want to reduce hideKeyboard function just use

```
view.endEditing(true)
```

Comment: Thank u very much