# UITap gesture recognized crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have tableview has multiple headers one of this header has UIView, and UIView Contains

1- UIImageView

2- UIlabel

After I have added UITapGesture in the UIImageView, and  when I press this image will navigate to another screen

--My problem is

when I add UITapGesture to imageView , and try to press it application crash with this message

***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView showHint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1693efb30'**

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(showHint))
        hintImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        hintImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    @objc func showHint(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("hi")
    }
```

Comment: Change `target` from `view` to `self`. The target is the one that has the selector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unrecognized selector with UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767973/unrecognized-selector-with-uitapgesturerecognizer)

Comment: thank you very much when I changed from view to self solved the problem